# Laravel. Pass parameters to an event subscriber

Tags: php, events, laravel-4, event-handling

Im developing a task system and i want to mark as viewed a task and do other things when a user request the task

I wrote a Task Event Subscriber like this

```
<?php namespace Athena\Events;

class TaskEventSubscriber {


    public function onCreate($event)
    {
       // Here we can send a lot of emails
    }


    public function onUpdate($event)
    {
        \Log::info('This is some useful information.');
    }

    public function onShow($event)
    {
        \Log::info('The view event is now triggerd ');
    }


    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen('user.create', 'Athena\Events\TaskEventSubscriber@onCreate');

        $events->listen('user.update', 'Athena\Events\TaskEventSubscriber@onUpdate');

        $events->listen('task.show', 'Athena\Events\TaskEventSubscriber@onShow');
    }
}
```

And my controller I fire the event like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $canView = $this->canView($id);
    if($canView !== true)
    {
        return $canView;
    }

    $task = $this->task->byId($id);
    // We fire the showed event
    $this->events->fire('task.show', $this->task);
    return View::make('tasks.show')
        ->with('task', $task);
}
```

But i dont know how can I or I should catch a parameter to be used inside of the event

By the way my Task Event subscriber is register on this Service Provider

```
class AthenaServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        // A lot of stuffs
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        \Event::subscribe('Athena\Events\UserEventSubscriber');
        \Event::subscribe('Athena\Events\TaskEventSubscriber');
    }
```

}

If you need more information just let me know, Thnks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how to feel already... 
I am passing the values what i need to my event there are on $event variable of each function

Note: if you need to send more than one value just put them into an array and set your event function to catch them like parameters

Answer (score 2):

You will need to declare an Event object like this

```
<?php namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TriggerShowTask extends Event {

    use SerializesModels;

    public $task;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }
}
```

When you trigger the event with

```
\Event::fire(TriggerShowTask, $this->task);
```

The `$task`object will be passed to the event

You can then access it in the subscriber with

```
public function onShow($event)
{
    $event->task; // A Task object
    \Log::info('The view event is now triggerd ');
}
```